# Make a grid using ngfor and ngif

Tags: angular, mdbootstrap

I'm trying to make a grid where 3 cards are displayed in one line, then a new row is added, and the next 3 cards are displayed.

This is the code I have at the moment:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div *ngIf="recipes$ | async as recipes; else loadingOrError">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col" *ngFor="let recipe of recipes; let i = index">
        <app-recipe [recipe]="recipe"></app-recipe>
        <div *ngIf="i % 3 === 0">
          <div class="row"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <ng-template #loadingOrError></ng-template>
  </div>
</div>
```

This does not work. Is there an easier way to complete this task?
I'm using the [mdbootstrap](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/) framework.

Comment: Do you have `.row-cols-*` available (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/#row-columns) ?

Comment: I would advise using `flexbox` here, allowing for wrapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you're using mdbootstrap, but this is an ideal scenario for CSS grid. If you cannot get mdbootstrap to work for you, consider this alternative:

Your template:

```
<div class="container" *ngIf="recipes$ | async as recipes; else loadingOrError">
  <div class="card" *ngFor="let recipe of recipes; let i = index">
    <app-recipe [recipe]="recipe"></app-recipe>
    <div *ngIf="i % 3 === 0">
      <div class="row"></div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
<ng-template #loadingOrError></ng-template>
```

Your CSS:

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1em;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

If you want an interactive example, take a look at this [codepen](https://codepen.io/kylerjohnson26/pen/dyPKorN). The hard-coded `div` elements are simulating the elements generated by the `*ngFor` directive.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about suing CSS Grid, I'll play around with it!